# Cannot connect to Azure SQL Database with specific user(s)

Tags: azure, permissions, connection, azure-sql-database

I want to connect to an Azure SQL Database with a specific user in SSMS and pyodbc, respectively. I added this user without a problem using my sysadmin user (login and connecting with sysadmin is no problem in SMSS & pyodbc). I have multiple users, none of them can connect to the database.

To add the users I used following steps as described on [azure's blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/) post:

```
1. create login
2. create user
```

The login is visible on server level and the user on the database level. They have the necessary roles etc. The engineeruser is in fact `db_owner`.

When I check `SELECT name, is_disabled FROM sys.sql_logins;` All users are enabled.

[image]

I try to login in SSMS explicity stating the database.
[image]

[image]

But I receive the following error:

> Login failed for user '_engineeruser'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: The error is basically indicate that password is incorrect

Comment: Hi, I copy the password from the create login statement - so it is unlikely an error occuring from a wrong password. I dropped and regenerated a user and the behaviour persists.

Comment: check this https://appuals.com/sql-server-error-18456/#:~:text=The%20error%20code%2018456%20in%20the%20SQL%20server,SQL%20Server%20Configuration%20Manager%20may%20solve%20the%20problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To connect to Azure SQL Database with specific user(s)**

Using SSMS as an admin in master, establish a connection to your Azure SQL Database server. Construct a database user mapped to the login, then create a SQL authentication login with the password

```sql
CREATE LOGIN demologin1 WITH PASSWORD=N'qwertyuiop@29'
GO
```

Open another query window and choose your database in the dropdown.
[image]

then create user in that database with login created previously with same name as login.

```sql
CREATE USER demologin1 FOR LOGIN demologin1 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'demologin1'
GO
```

**Execution:**

[image]